# How to pause gazebo at the start in foxy?

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im want to start the simulation at pause state with the launch file. some one can help me? tks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412264/how-to-pause-gazebo-at-the-start-in-foxy?/) by [nino](https://answers.ros.org/users/136990/nino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2023-02-08**:
Probably you should provide with version of Gazebo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a `pause` Launch Argument that you can set to `true` ([defined here in the source](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/foxy/gazebo_ros/launch/gzserver.launch.py#L105))

Your launch command could look something like this:

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = LaunchDescription()
    gz_launch_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')
    ld.add_action(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(gz_launch_path), 
            launch_arguments={'pause': 'true'}.items()
    ))
    return ld
```

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2023-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nino](https://answers.ros.org/users/136990/nino/) on 2023-02-12**:
Thks for your support.
I have solved this by add this code in launch file

```
   load_gazebo= ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gazebo', '-u', "-s","libgazebo_ros_factory.so"],
    output='screen')
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-14**:
@shonigmann: could you please not *close* questions when they have an accepted answer? Askbot displays those mostly as `[closed]`, which makes it look like there was no resolution. Accepting an answer already marks the question as answered, without needing to close it.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2023-02-14**:
I'm not familiar with Askbot, but my intent was always to help people coming to ROS Answers to *answer* questions more readily find questions that haven't yet been resolved. But if its making things less visible, I can certainly save myself that step and avoid closing questions. Thanks for the feedback

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-14**:
Askbot is the software platform behind ROS Answers.

> my intent was always to help people coming to ROS Answers to answer questions more readily find questions that haven't yet been resolved

of course. I never doubted that.

But answered questions are already clearly marked as such, while closing them makes the "this is closed" part stand out more. So just accepting the correct answer would be enough.